# Get distinct or groupby list using linq of object property

Tags: c#, linq

I have

```
List<ObjA>  
ObjA has ObjB  
ObjB has property Id
```

How do I get a list of distinct ObjB based on Id?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `ObjA has ObjB`?

Comment: ObjA has a single property which is ObjB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [DistinctBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) from [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), you can use this:

```
list.Select(a => a.ObjB).DistinctBy(b => b.Id);
```

Comment: Impressive, thank you very much for the linq to that webpage ;P

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your own `IEqualityComparer<ObjB>` to compare ObjBs using only their Id property. Then you can do:

```
class ObjBEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ObjB> {
    public bool Equals(ObjB x, ObjB y) {
        return x.Id.Equals(y.Id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ObjB o) {
        return o.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

var objBComparer = new ObjBEqualityComparer();
var result = objAList.Select(o => o.ObjB).Distinct(objBComparer);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've overriden `.Equals()` on `ObjB` so that items with the same ID are considered equal (and items with different ID considered unequal), you can do

```
var list = GetListOfAs();

var distinctBs = list.Select(a => a.B).Distinct();
```

As Daniel Hilgarth noted in his answer, there is an extension library called [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), in which there is a method called `DistinctBy`. With that, you don't need to override `Equals` at all - instead, just call

```
var distinctBs = list.Select(a => a.B).DistinctBy(b => b.ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<ObjA> lst;
// ...
var distinctById = lst.Select(a => a.b) // get all B's
    .GroupBy(b => b.id)                 // group by id's
    .Select(g => g.First());            // take one object of each id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without the need of extensions:

```
List<ObjB> distinctObjB = lst
  .GroupBy(a => a.MyObjB.Id)
  .Select(b => b.First().MyObjB)
  .ToList();
```